# Can the sorting of a list be verified without comparing neighbors?

Tags: sorting

A $n$-item list can be verified as sorted by comparing every item to its neighbor. In my application, I will not be able to compare *every* item with its neighbor: instead, the comparisons will sometimes be between distant elements. Given that the list contains more than three items and also that comparison is the only supported operation, does there ever exist a "network" of comparisons that will prove that the list is sorted, but is missing at least one direct neighbor-to-neighbor comparison?

Formally, for a sequence of elements $e_i$, I have a set of pairs of indices $(j,k)$ for which I know whether $e_j > e_k$, $e_j = e_k$, or $e_j < e_k$. There exists a pair $(l,l+1)$ that is missing from the set of comparisons. Is it ever possible, then, to prove that the sequence is sorted?

Comment: A note in case anyone finds this page later with the question of whether you can verify a list is sorted without comparing anything; Only if you can put some limits on the inputs, and/or know something about the shape of the inputs; (e.g. radix sort).

Comment: There is, however, the possibility of optimizing the number of comparisons used in cases where it's *not* sorted.

Comment: @Acccumulation Is there actually such a possibility? Should be trivial to take any such program and cook up an adversarial list of length n that forces the program to do n-1 comparisons. See also [A Killer Adversary for QuickSort](https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~doug/mdmspe.pdf), which takes this idea even further to forcing quicksort into the bad part of its asymptotic analysis.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes, such optimization has to be done with respect to expected input of the particular application.

Comment: Probably not possible. But please clarify: did you mean that you only know the comparisons of the form (j,j+1), not general (j,k)? For example, do you ever know the comparison of two items of indices (j,j+3) ?

Comment: Did you consider the simplest non-trivial case, sorting two elements $e_1$ and $e_2$, where the comparison between $e_1$ and $e_2$ is missing? Is it possible to prove either $e_1, e_2$ or $e_2, e_1$ is sorted?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is impossible. Suppose that you have the result of *all* comparisons except for the pair $(i,i+1)$. Then you wouldn't be able to distinguish between the following two cases:
$$
1,2,\ldots,i-1,i,i+1,i+2,\ldots,n \\
1,2,\ldots,i-1,i+1,i,i+2,\ldots,n
$$